# Como implementar una plantilla en Laravel Inertia

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Tengo un dilema de que no se como implementar una plantilla html  de Metronic a Laravel Inertia, es decir, quiero comenzar a usar el login que trae la plantilla pero veo que el login termina en .vue, y la verdad no tengo de idea de como hacerlo, si tienen algún tutorial o sugerencia de como podría implementar lo del login y un dashboard, estaría muy agradecido.